# If '<x>' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having trouble with Angular's components. My app is using only one module (app.module). I have created a component called 'BooksComponent' with a selector 'app-books' for html. When I use it in app.component I get this error:

> 'app-books' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'app-books' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'app-books' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

my code is like this:

**books.component.ts**

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Book } from '../book';
import { BOOKS } from '../mock-books';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-books',
  templateUrl: './books.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./books.component.css']
})
export class BooksComponent implements OnInit {

        books = BOOKS;
        selectedBook : Book;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**app.component.ts**

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<h1>{{title}}</h1>
            <app-books></app-books>`
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'BookShelf';
}
```

and finally: 
**app.module.ts**

```html
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BooksComponent } from './books/books.component';
import { BookDetailComponent } from './book-detail/book-detail.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BooksComponent,
    BookDetailComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I have declared and import BooksComponent in app module so i can't understand what i am missing! please help!

Comment: have you created component with 'ng g c books' ?i think there is apparently no error in your code.

Comment: One thing - you miss a comma after `<app-books></app-books>`, but wonder if that could cause your error

Comment: yes i created component with ng genetate.. 
@J.D. you were right i added the comma but still i get the same error...

Answer (score 23):

If you get the error when running the tests, that could mean that the spec needs to know about the new component **BooksComponent**.

In order to fix this issue, add the following to your **app.component.spec.ts** file.

```
import { BooksComponent } from './books/books.component';
```

And in the declarations of the **beforeEach**() method, add the new component like the following:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent, BooksComponent
    ],
  }).compileComponents();
}));
```

Comment: What is `TestBed` here? And where comes the `beforeEach`?

Comment: @YanYang, TestBed - "Configures and initializes environment for unit testing and provides methods for creating components and services in unit tests." https://angular.io/api/core/testing/TestBed

Answer (score 4):

For me the issue seemed to be VSCode extension Angular snippets for Angular 8 by John Papa.(That is if you have declared you component in the app-module and error persists). Disabling the extension made issue go away for me